# Admob SMART_BANNER size

Tags: android, admob

The AdSize class has getWidthInPixels() and getHeightInPixels() methods to obtain size of the ad. Although, they work correctly for BANNER, they don't work SMART_BANNER. They always return -2.

Can you please suggest me a way to fetch AdView size during run-time?

Answer (score 19):

If you're using the Google Play services library, you can simply use:

```
int widthPixels = AdSize.SMART_BANNER.getWidthInPixels(this);
int heightPixels = AdSize.SMART_BANNER.getHeightInPixels(this);
```

---

In the old standalone Android AdMob SDK, you have to do it the hacky way:

*Disclaimer: This is the incorrect way to create an AdSize. **Do NOT pass this AdSize into the AdView constructor!***

Hopefully the smart banner implementation will be fixed in future versions so you don't have to do this hacky workaround. But here is how it can be done:

```
// This testSize should not be passed to the AdView constructor.
// Always pass AdSize.SMART_BANNER instead.
AdSize testSize = AdSize.createAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER, this);
int widthPixels = testSize.getWidthInPixels(this);
int heightPixels = testSize.getHeightInPixels(this);
// testSize should not be referenced past this point.
```