# How do I get the height of a SMART_BANNER AdView in Android?

Tags: java, android, admob, banner

I have a SMART_BANNER at the foot of my application. I want to reserve the same amount of space at the top of my application (just for prettification purposes). SMART_BANNER can be mixed height so I need to find out what the height is once the Ad in the AdView has been drawn.

So far I have put this in a method in my MainActivity:

```
    this.adView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {
            int height = adView.getHeight();

            if (height > 0)
            {
//Some Crazy Stuff goes down HERE
}}};
```

...but onGlobalLayout is never called.

What do I do to get the height of the SMART_BANNER once it has been drawn?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162819/admob-smart-banner-size

Comment: Cool Thanks :) Sorted