# Android, AdMob banner, adding a close button

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I'm trying to allow my users to close an ad by placing a close button next to it.
I cant seem to position the button, when I use RelativeLayout and set the button to be right of the ad view, the button floats on top of it.

I've tried using Linear Layout as well but it didnt work as well... (I'm probably using gravity wrong)

When the ad loads, it pushed the button out of the screen

Edit: It seems that SMART_BANNERs are programmed to spread the entire width of the screen

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >   


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView   
              android:id="@+id/adView"                       
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-"
                         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                         />

        <Button
               android:id="@+id/buttonTEST"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="x" />



    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot and possibly your xml as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should use RelativeLayout for the outside and let both AdView and Button align to the same side. You can calculate width and height from AdSize to adjust your button position.

To calculate AdSize, try this
[Admob SMART_BANNER size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162819/admob-smart-banner-size/14204959#14204959)