# Determining actual height of an Admob SmartBanner in Unity for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

So I'm implementing admob banners into my Unity 4.6 Android game. I have the banner at the bottom and need to account for it in my UI. Specifically I need to know exactly how tall it is, but I'm having trouble with figuring this out.

Based on the information found [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner) the Smart Banner should be 32, 50, or 90 pixels tall, depending on device height. This doesn't seem to typically be the case though.

Some searching would seem to indicate this is because of density pixels. So I attempt to convert the stated pixel height using px = dp * (Screen.dpi/ 160). So for example if I determine the banner height should be 90 pixels, I would use bannerHeight = 90 * (Screen.dpi / 160). This seems to work on some devices but not others.

For example my Nexus 4 has a DPI of 320. Using the above it would seem to indicate that the banner should be 180 pixels tall, but the banner appears to actually be about 90 pixels tall. But on the Nexus 7 (which has a dpi of 166), the banner appears to be about 120 pixels tall when the formula would indicate it should be ~93.

So I guess I have no idea how to figure out how tall the banner is actually going to be, and I haven't found a way to get this information from the API. My code for calling the banner is pretty stock:

```
 string adUnitId = "my_id";

 BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);
 AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
 bannerView.LoadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 8):

First you need to calculate which Ads google will give you (32 or 50 or 90 ?)
for this you can calculate it by screen sizes.

> height/dpi = actual height in inches

so, Google says above 720 (with dp of 160dpi) is acctauly 
720/160 = 4.5 inch height, above this height, the ads are 90 pixels (dp!)
below its 50 dp!
400/160 = 2.5 , below this, ads will be 32 dp

SO!
if i have Xiaomi mi3 with 1920x1080
thats,
1920/480dpi = 4 inch height..which will give us 50 dp ads.

with the formula of converting DP to pixel

> px = dp * (Screen.dpi/ 160)

50 * (480/160) = 150 pixels height for the ad!

For landscape you need to use as "height" 1080 instead of 1920
1080/480dpi = 2.25 height in landscape
this means the ads will be 32 pixels dp

which converts to:

```
32* (480/160) = 96 pixels in landscape
```

its too bad google doesn't give enough examples so we can really check ourselves.

Your info page is:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Answer (score 7):

There is answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14204959/1900546

```
int heightPixels = AdSize.SMART_BANNER.getHeightInPixels(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

The following function may come in handy to those of you using Admob Smart Banners:

```
public static float adHeight(){
    float f = Screen.dpi / 160f;
    float dp = Screen.height / f;
    return (dp>720f)? 90f * f
          :(dp>400f)? 50f * f
          :32f * f;
}
```

To use it:

```
r.offsetMin = new Vector2(r.offsetMin.x, adHeight());
```

where r is the RectTransform of the fullscreen Canvas / Panel.

I am attaching a 'loadBannerAd' script to every panel which requires it.

Answer (score 0):

The link you gave says that the Smart banner will have a height of

1. 32 dp for phones in landscape
2. 50 dp for phones in portrait
3. 90 dp for tablets in either orientation

Let's take the two examples you gave.

The Nexus 4 has a DPI of ~320 dp. Given that it's a phone, it'll have an ad with a height of 50 dp.
Using the formula, it works out to 50 * 320 / 160 = 100 pixels (close to your actual banner's height)

The Nexus 7s I looked up have either a 216 dp (2012) or 323 dp (2013), so I don't quite know which model has 166 dp.
But let's assume that it's 216 dp, then being a tablet, ad height in dp is 90. Therefore, pixels = 90 * 216 / 160 = 121.5, once again close to your banner's actual height.

I realize that Google has also mentioned the following

1. For devices with heights between 400 & 720, an ad with a height of 50 is used
2. For devices with heights above 720, an ad with a height of 90 is used.

However, I believe that the 400 & 720 MIGHT also be expressed in dp? i.e. 400 pixels in an mdpi device. Your Nexus 4 being an xhdpi device (320 dp), with a height of 1280 pixels then would be the same as an mdpi device of height 640 pixels, falling within the range for an ad height of 50 dp.

Bottomline, your calculations seem valid. Stick to the first set of rules, and you should see consistent results.

Comment: I'm getting 90dp height on Google Pixel 3XL in LANDSCAPE. I had to brute force height for 32dp.

Comment: Same for portrait. But when I brute force height it's clipping the bigger banner.

Answer (score -4):

```
bannerView.SetPosition(AdPosition.Top);
```

or something similar to this is how you change a position of an active banner